# Building dynamic query for large files

Tags: java, sql, oracle, performance

I am trying to load a large text file (between **400-800MB**) and for the file I want to insert the records into database, however I am running into performance problems and memory issues (not enough *heap space*). I was wondering if there are better approach from what I am currently doing.

So the text file that I am loading has simple format, it would be something like:

```
00000  Andy   8920  N  UNL  ...
00001  Roger  4428  N  TRX  ...
,,,
```

**Current Approach**: read each line, get the fields, and build the query

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fields = ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> data= new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.length() >= 6)
        data.add(line.substring(0, 6)); 
    if(line.length() >= 24)
        data.add(line.substring(6, 15));  
    if(line.length() >= 30)
        data.add(line.substring(15, 20)); 
    if(line.length() >= 48)
        data.add(line.substring(20, 25));
...
    fields.add(data); //it looks like [[00000, Andy   , 8920,..],[00001, Roger, ...]]
} //end read
System.gc();
db.insertValues(input);
```

**DB Code**

```
public void insertValues(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data) {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("Insert into CUST_ACCT "
                    + "(CID,NAME,R_NUM,CKM_IND,DATE_1,DATE_2,DATE_3,DATE_4,DATE_5,DATE_6,DATE_7,DATE_8,DATE_9,DATE_10,NUMBER_1,NUMBER_2,NUMBER_3,NUMBER_4,NUMBER_5,NUMBER_6,NUMBER_7,NUMBER_8,NUMBER_9,NUMBER_10,STRING_1,STRING_2,STRING_3,STRING_4,STRING_5,STRING_6,STRING_7,STRING_8,STRING_9,STRING_10,GUID,PARN_GUID,LAST_UPDT_DATE_TIME_STAMP)"
                    + " values "
                    + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,sysdate)");
for(int i=0; i< data.size(); i++) {
                ps.setString(1, data.get(i).get(0)); //0
                ps.setString(2, data.get(i).get(1)); //1
                ps.setString(3, data.get(i).get(2)); //2
                ps.setString(4, data.get(i).get(3)); //3
        ...
        ps.addBatch();
        }
        int[] i = ps.executeBatch();
        log.info("total of record inserted: "+i.length);
    }
```

However I am getting _e_rror with `Not enough heap space` errors and I have also attempted to build query but then it would insert records one by one which after an hour it would only insert around **20k** records out of millions. Is there a better way to load the data?

Comment: You shouldn't put the whole content in memory, read the file by chunks (e.g 100 lines), then use the batch insert after each read chunk .

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an automatic import function in your DBMS for this kind of file.

Comment: As @Berger said, create reasonable batches (every 100 or 1000 rows, execute the batch and start the next). A medium-sized Oracle server then should be able to import 100 ... 1000 of such rows per second.

Comment: While I agree file size is part of the problem but I think the issue is also part of the arraylist within arraylist, when I build the dynamic query with the entire file size it was fine if I increase the heap size, but adding the arraylist of arraylist cause it out of heap immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load all the file in memory and then try to read all of it line by line, and this lead to performance and memory problem (heap space, etc...)

You could read the file using `Scanner`, this way read it line by line without loading into memory.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
Scanner sc = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        // db insert!
    }
    if (sc.ioException() != null) {
        throw sc.ioException();
    }
} finally {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    if (sc != null) {
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Otherwise using Apache Commons IO

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(theFile, "UTF-8");
try {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String line = it.nextLine();
        // do something with line
        // db insert
    }
} finally {
    LineIterator.closeQuietly(it);
}
```

For enanched performance I suggest you to open connection only one time

```
   // your logic....
   Connection con = getConnection();
   // reading file logic
   while (it.hasNext()) {
        String line = it.nextLine();
        // do something with line
        insertValues(con, line);
        // other logic
   }
   // checking exception etc
   } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }

        if (con != null ) {
            con.close();
        }

    }
```

Summing it up:

1. Read file line by line without loading into memory
2. Open connection only one time (or few times and not for every insert).
3. Pass connection object to your insert method
4. close everything when done.

Hope you understand... those are simple examples and you need to chenge them based on your needs!

Answer (score 1):

Don't read the whole file - read 1000 lines, then insert them using a prepared statement and commit the transaction after this. Then read another 1000, ...

Also I think Oracle has a special tool to load data (google SQL*Loader and Data pump).

Answer (score -1):

let me see if I correctly understood your needs:

You have a large file and each line from the file, you need to insert into oen ore more tables in database. Did I understand correctly?

If yes, have you try using the ["SQL*Loader"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm) tool from Oracle? 
I didn't test it for such a large file but it may be a sollution. 
You can call it from you Java app.